# Using results of a callback in node in a separate function

Tags: javascript, node.js, q

I'm probably missing the point somewhere here so I'm looking for advice.

I have a nodejs server which is listening for client connections and, based on the data received, makes calls to an API.

The very first call to that API gets an ID which needs to be used on subsequent calls to group them together.

Where I'm struggling is that the call to the API is necessarily asynchronous and in the callback I'm assigning the ID to a variable. While that async call is being processed by the API server, more data is coming in from the client and needs more API calls made BUT I can't fire them until I know the results from the first call as the second calls depend on it.

What's the proper way to handle this? I feel like I should be using Q to promise the results of the first API call to the second, but I'm not sure how it should be structured. Or should I just be queueing up the API calls until the first completes? How would I do that?

Example problem code :

```
var server = net.createServer();

//set up the callback handler 

server.on('connection', handleConnection);

handleConnection(conn) {
  //do some stuff...
  firstAPICall();
  conn.on('data', handleData);
}

handleData(data) {
  //do some stuff...
  otherAPIcall();
}

firstAPICall() {
  client.get("http://myAPI/getID", function (data, response) {
    conn.myID = data[0].myID;
    }
  }
}

otherAPICall() {
  //How do I make sure I actually have a value
  //in conn.myID from the first function???
  client.post("http://myAPI/storeData", { data: {myID:conn.myID, data:someData} }, function (data, response) {
    //do some stuff...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The point you are missing is that "The very first call to that API gets an ID which needs to be used on subsequent calls to group them together".  Either it's a requirement, or it's not.  Make up your mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should be using promises for this. Make a promise for the id that is asynchronously resolved from the first call, and then use it in the subsequent calls:

```
handleConnection(conn) {
  //do some stuff...
  var idPromise = firstAPICall();
  conn.on('data', function handleData(data) {
    //do some stuff...
    otherAPIcall(idPromise).then(function(result) {
      …
    });
  });
}

firstAPICall() {
  return Q.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    client.get("http://myAPI/getID", function (data, response) {
      resolve(data[0].myID);
    });
  });
}

otherAPICall(idPromise) {
  return idPromise.then(function(myID) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      client.post("http://myAPI/storeData", {
        data: {myID:myID, data:someData}
      }, function (data, response) {
        //do some stuff...
        resolve(…);
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Probably you should factor out creating a promise for the result of a `client.get` call in an extra function. Also make sure to handle errors correctly there and call `reject` with them. If `client` would use the node callback conventions, Q even has [some nice helper functions](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#interfacing-with-nodejs-callbacks) for that.

Comment: I went with promises in the end and it seems to be working well - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using promises. Then use 'then' to call the otherAPICall()

Answer (score 0):

I think you can assume they will be sending data immediately after connecting.  So you can simplify and just check in otherAPICall if you have an ID, if not, you can just use a callback.  Promises or the `async/await` keywords might make things sort of nicer down the line but aren't required for this.

```
var server = net.createServer();

//set up the callback handler 

server.on('connection', handleConnection);

handleConnection(conn) {
  conn.on('data', handleData(connm, data));
}

handleData(conn, data) {
  //do some stuff...
  otherAPIcall(conn);
}

checkID(conn, cb) {
  if (!conn.myID) {
    client.get("http://myAPI/getID", function (data, response) {
      conn.myID = data[0].myID;
      cb();
    });
  } else {
    cb();
  }
}

otherAPICall(conn) {
  checkID(conn, function() {
    client.post("http://myAPI/storeData", { data: {myID:conn.myID, data:someData} }, function (data, response) {
      //do some stuff...
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

promises can chain values and are always resolved after the callback occurs with the returned value,

```
function async(value) { 
var deferred = $q.defer();
var asyncCalculation = value / 2;
deferred.resolve(asyncCalculation);
return deferred.promise;
}

var promise = async(8) 
.then(function(x) {
    return x+1;
})
.then(function(x) {
    return x*2;
})
.then(function(x) {
    return x-1;
});
promise.then(function(x) { 
console.log(x);
});
```

This value passes through all the success callbacks and so the value 9 is logged ((8 / 2 + 1) * 2 - 1).

Comment: Yes, that's how promises work, but what does this have to do with the question?

Comment: Btw, OP is using Q, not Angular promises.

Comment: The case is show how promise work clearly and how to use it. If I understand promise well, Whatever Q or Angularjs $q, they are based on the same principle. If you understand how promise work, how come you can not use it in another area.